# Почему Ошибка 500 при открытии страниц одновременно?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, vesta, http-status-code-500

есть сервер vestacp+nginx+php-fpm + 2 таких же сервера связанные через nginx balancer в равных пропорциях, если открывать сайт по одной странице, то все нормально, если попытаться открыть много страниц сразу, то на части появляется ошибка 500

При этом в логах чисто на всех серверах и если в момент открытия смотреть на нагрузку, то нет ничего необычного, повышения даже не видно...

Пробовал запускать нагрузочное тестирование http://loadme.socialtalents.com в 8 потоков на 20 страниц, больше половины ошибка 500, но нагрузка судя по htop не поднимается!, хотя если запустить на одну страницу, то держит без ошибок 80 потоков и нагрузку видно...

Подскажите, куда копать? Где найти это невидимое на первый взгляд узкое место?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Это ошибка связана с нарушением работы северной стороны. Нагрузка потому и не поднимается, что сервер падает. Так что копайте сервер

Comment: смотрите лог error.log